# Change excel file content zoom in pdf file

Tags: c#, spire.xls

I`m converting excel file to pdf. Excel document has greater width that A4 format and I want excel file content to zoom and fit A4 page size.

I`ve tried next way

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(fullpath, ExcelVersion.Version2007);

Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter(workbook);
sheet.ViewMode = ViewMode.Preview;
sheet.ZoomScalePageBreakView = 80;

PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
pdfDocument.PageSettings.Size = PdfPageSize.A4;

PdfConverterSettings settings = new PdfConverterSettings();
settings.TemplateDocument = pdfDocument;
pdfDocument = pdfConverter.Convert(settings);

pdfDocument.SaveToFile("test.pdf");
```

I got pdf document, where one sheet devides on several parts and accomodates on several pages instead of desirable single page. Does anyone knows how to solve that problem? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try use the below code to shrink excel content to fit pdf page:

```
sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1;
//......
```

Or:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(fullpath, ExcelVersion.Version2007);
workbook.ConverterSetting.SheetFitToPage = true;
workbook.SaveToFile("test.pdf", FileFormat.PDF);
```

Comment: @OleksaKachmarskyi Can you share the excel file for a check?

Comment: thanks, but i've already solved that problem. The problem was in Excel file,  size changes were needed

Answer (score 0):

In order to save Excel as A4 size PDF, it may be necessary to change the excel settings according to the excel version.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Keyxls = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\16.0\\Excel\\Options", true);
if (Keyxls != null)
{
    Keyxls.SetValue("A4Letter", "0", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    Keyxls.Close();
}
```